# How to clone files from Github to VM using Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have started learn Jenkins and here is an entry task).

I have a small website on GitHub(html and css files) and a Linux server(virtual machine).
How can I clone files from git to a virtual machine in a '/var/www/' folder.

For instance:
Jenkins server running on 192.168.10.10, destination VM on 192.168.2.30.

So, at first I should clone this repo to my agent(192.168.10.10 '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/') and from there copy to my VM?

It will look like

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  
  stage ('Clone the git project'){
      step{
      git 'https://github.com/my_prod’
    }
 }
}
```

And then?

I've read documentation, but can't understand how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using both Linux servers. Before copying the files make sure your Jenkins server has access to the vm that you're copying files to. If not follow this [ssh between two servers][1] to provide the access to the Jenkins server

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  
  stage ('Clone the git project'){
      step{
      git 'https://github.com/my_prod’
      script{
        scp user1@remote1:/home/user1/file1.txt user2@remote2:/home/user2/file1.txt
        }
    }
 }
}


  [1]: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-copy-a-file-between-two-remote-ssh-servers/
```